# Why can't I specify NamedArgs and item elements on cellFactory?

Tags: javafx, tableview, coercion

I have the following tableView in fxml

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="525.0" prefWidth="814.0">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0">
      <graphic><ToggleButton fx:id="mainToggleButton" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#onMainToggleButtonAction" text="Start all" /></graphic>
      <cellFactory><ToggleButtonTableCellFactory maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" activatedText="Started" deactivatedText="Stopped"/></cellFactory>
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="state"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Side">
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="side"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Source">
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="sourceContract"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Reference" editable="true">
      <cellFactory>
        <ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
          <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <String fx:value="r01" />
              <String fx:value="r02" />
            </FXCollections>
          </items>
        </ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory>
      </cellFactory>
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="referenceContract"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Destination">
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="destinationContract"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Margin" editable="true">
      <cellFactory><SpinnerTableCellFactory maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" min="0" max="1" initialValue="0" amountToStepBy="0.025" decimalFormat="0.000"/></cellFactory>
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="margin"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Bot">
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="bot"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Price">
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="price"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Volume">
      <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="volume"/></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
  </columns>
  <items>
    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
      <GridRowModel state="false" side="BID" sourceContract="s01" referenceContract="r01" destinationContract="d01" margin="0" bot="MinMax" price="15.125" volume="0" />
      <GridRowModel state="false" side="ASK" sourceContract="s02" referenceContract="r01" destinationContract="d02" margin="0" bot="MinMax" price="15.125" volume="0" />
    </FXCollections>
  </items>
</TableView>
```

The `ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory` has a constructor which takes both named arguments from the fxml and a setter for the items element.

```
public class ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> {

  private ObservableList<String> items;
  private double maxHeight;
  private double maxWidth;

  public ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory() {
  }

  public ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory(
    @NamedArg("maxHeight") double maxHeight,
    @NamedArg("maxWidth") double maxWidth) {
    this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
    this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
  }

  @Override
  public TableCell<S, String> call(TableColumn<S, String> param) {
    return new TableCell<S, String>() {

      ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>(getItems());

      {
        choiceBox.setMaxHeight(maxHeight);
        choiceBox.setMaxWidth(maxWidth);
        choiceBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
          ObservableValue<String> value = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
          if (value instanceof WritableValue) {
            ((WritableValue<String>) value).setValue(newValue);
          }
        });
      }

      @Override
      protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
          setText(null);
          setGraphic(null);
        } else {
          if (isEditing()) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
          } else {
            choiceBox.setValue(item);
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(choiceBox);
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  public ObservableList<String> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  public void setItems(ObservableList<String> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }
}
```

But that throws this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce [[r01, r02]] to interface javafx.collections.ObservableList.
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:496)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.ProxyBuilder$Setter.invoke(ProxyBuilder.java:533)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.ProxyBuilder.createObjectFromDefaultConstructor(ProxyBuilder.java:338)
    ... 144 more
```

When I remove the `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` attributes the items field is set correctly through the setter. With these attributes the items value is wrapped in an additional array. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Do you need the `setItems` method anywhere else in your code? If not, you could try removing it, and using `<items><String fx:value="r01"/>...</items>`.

Comment: when I remove the `setItems` setter i get this error
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create instance of com.rwe.st.cao.gas.attila.ui.control.ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory with given set of properties: [maxHeight, items, maxWidth]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it should work. I tried a simpler test and the following workarounds seemed to work there:

If you don't need the `setItems()` method anywhere else in your code, remove it and use the [read only list properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements) approach. I.e. remove the `setItems(...)` method entirely, and in the FXML do

```
    <ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
      <items>
        <String fx:value="r01" />
        <String fx:value="r02" />
      </items>
    </ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory>
```

The other way around seems to be to use an `<fx:define>` block to define the items, and initialize it using an attribute:

```
<fx:define>
    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" fx:id="items">
        <String fx:value="r01"/>
        <String fx:value="r02"/>
    </FXCollections>
<fx:define>
<ChoiceBoxTableCellFactory maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
    items="$items" />
```

Comment: The picked the solution with fx:define, works. My first approach looks like a bug in javafx.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be confused by `@NamedArg` when you mix attribute properties and element properties.

Comment: Can I fill a bug report somewhere?